# Swift 4 Firebase Auth custom error code

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, label, swift4

I tried to define custom error codes to Firebase Auth with this code:

```
extension AuthErrorCode {
    var errorMessage: String {
        switch self {
        case .emailAlreadyInUse:
            return "Ezzel a névvel már létezik rendezvény"
        case .invalidEmail:
            return "Hibás formátum: Rendezvény neve. Kérlek ne használj speciális karaktereket és szóközt"
        case .userNotFound:
            return "Ezzel a névvel nem létezik rendezvény"
        case .networkError:
            return "Hálózat nem elérhető. Próbáld meg később"
        case .weakPassword:
            return "A jelszó túl gyenge. Legalább 6 karakter hosszúnak kell lennie."
        case .wrongPassword:
            return "Hibás jelszó"
        default:
            return "Unknown error occurred"
        }
    }
}
```

And after reach this codes in checkLogin() method:

```
func checkLogin(){
if eventNameTextField.text != "" && passwordTextField.text != "" {
    let eventname = eventNameTextField.text! + "@somemail.com"

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: eventname, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
        if user != nil {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMain", sender: self)
        }
        else{
            if let myError = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: (error?._code)!) {
                self.errorLabel.text = myError.errorMessage
                print(myError.errorMessage)
            }
        }
    })
}
else {
    self.errorLabel.text = "A mezők kitöltése kötelező"
}
}
```

If I try to create a new user, it's work perfectly, but when I try to login with wrong password (or with invalid username), it says

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value"

to `self.errorLabel.text = myError.errorMessage`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGqov.png

If I remove the label, it's working perfectly and show me the error code in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your snapshot I'm assuming you are using xib or storyboard. Then **errorLabel** is not connected with **@IBOutlet** connect this. You are accessing label before initialisation.

Comment: Oh my god, you're right. I don't know how, but the errorLabel wasn't connected to storyboard label, because some days ago I used this label. Nevermind, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `errorLabel` is nil. As a result, when you try to assign `myError.errorMessage` to `errorLAbel.text` it crashes. The problem with your current code is that the errorLabel is not instantiated when you access its text value.

When you create a new user your app works because you don't assign anything to `errorLabel`.